# he @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "[topic].[group]. Errors ") annotation Is there an unresolvable Circular reference exception

Tags: java, spring, stream

describe:

hello
An exception occurred while using a channel that handles local exceptions,But it works fine

```java
   @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "force-logout-topic.force-logout-group.errors")
   public void handleError(ErrorMessage message) {
     log.info("原始消息体 = {}", message);
  }
```

```java
Could not register an MBean for: forceLogoutTopic.handleError.serviceActivator  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'forceLogoutTopic.handleError.serviceActivator': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

```java
2022-08-16 00:41:24,893 WARN  [force-logout-topic.force-logout-group-1,27c4d80edb2f6454,9142bcafd2fa2973] o.s.c.l.c.RoundRobinLoadBalancer.getInstanceResponse(98): No servers available for service: my-shop-auth-service  
2022-08-16 00:41:24,894 WARN  [force-logout-topic.force-logout-group-1,27c4d80edb2f6454,9142bcafd2fa2973] o.s.c.o.l.RetryableFeignBlockingLoadBalancerClient.lambda$execute$2(145): Service instance was not resolved, executing the original request
```

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      function:
        definition: forceLogoutConsumer
      bindings:
        forceLogoutConsumer-in-0:
          destination: force-logout-topic
          group: force-logout-group
        forceLogoutProducer:
          destination: force-logout-topic
          producer:
            error-channel-enabled: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a same problem,my spring-cloud-stream version is 3.1.3 ,debug found a logical problem, DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry class's method getSingleton gave your bean name [forceLogoutTopic.handleError.serviceActivator] multiple registrations.

In the end,I use @StreamListener replace @ServiceActivator fixed, It's working.

```
@StreamListener(IntegrationContextUtils.ERROR_CHANNEL_BEAN_NAME)
```

you can try:

```
@StreamListener("force-logout-topic.force-logout-group.errors")
```

singletonFactory.getObject() duplicate registration same bean name:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3EIz.png)